# #states in add node form

Tags: 7, nodes, javascript

How to use `#states` in add node form?
I don't experience any problems when use them with exposed filters (on user side), but cannot do the same when additing new nodes. 
I tried the following code:

```
function custom_module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'article_node_form') {
    $form['field_coordinate']['und'][0]['#default_value'] = t('1');
    $form['field_name_tag']['und']['0']['#states'] = array(
      'invisible' => array('select[id="edit-field-location-tag-und"]' => array('value' => '1')),
    ); 
  };
}
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: the semicolon `;` after the `if` block?

Comment: not, it didn't help

Comment: try using `'invisible' => array(':select[id="edit-field-location-tag-und"]' => array('value' => '1'))` ;note the `:` before select

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the state in the "value" key, so one level deeper as you tried.
E.g.:

```
$form['field_yourfieldname'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#states'] =
  array('visible' => 
    array('input[id="edit-field-otherfieldname"]' => array('checked' => TRUE))
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

The #states array has the following structure.

```
array(
  STATE1 => CONDITIONS_ARRAY1,
  STATE2 => CONDITIONS_ARRAY2,
  // ...
)
```

The condition array has the following structure.

```
array(
  JQUERY_SELECTOR1 => REMOTE_CONDITIONS1,
  JQUERY_SELECTOR2 => REMOTE_CONDITIONS2,
  // ...
)
```

JQUERY_SELECTOR is [a selector that is valid in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), such as `:input[name="foo"]`.